# Fullcalendar: back to selected date after postback

Tags: date, postback, fullcalendar

This question about jquery plugin fullcalendar.
How I can return to selected date after postback?..

For example, i have week agenda as default view. Assume I choose next week (custom week) and create the event in it. 
After postback I return to default week, but I want get custom week.

How can be resolved this issue?.. Please help!
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The javascript can get values from a property, so put the value into the session state before postback. On postback pull the value from the session state into the property. From the client then get the value from the property.

Server Side:

```
public string bar { get; set; }

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (IsPostBack)
        bar = Session["barvalue"].ToString();        
}
```

Client Side:

```
        $(document).ready(function() {
            var foo = '<%= bar %>';
            alert(foo);
        });
```

Comment: Thanks for reply! Page_Load is available in Web Forms, but I use MVC, and cannot access it...

Comment: Fair enough, but why not just put them in the action method?

Comment: Yes, I can store it to model and return view with this model in action method. Thanx a lot!

Answer (score 1):

You have to save the week number the users selected. In PHP you could use `$_SESSION` to save the selected week and when returning from the Event Creation Process the script gets this variable and shows that week.

```
session_start();
if (isset($_SESSION["week_number"]))
    $week_number = $_SESSION["week_number"];
else 
    $week_number = $this_week;

echo '<script>var week_number = '.$week_number.'; </script>';

// insert script to show the calendar here, use the variable week_number in your
// Javascript
```

and when the user clicks the "Next Week" button you have to tell that PHP with an AJAX call to a file like this:

```
<?php
    session_start();
    $_SESSION["week_number"] = $_GET["new_week_number"];
?>
```

Send the new week number to the file with the get param, i.e. `set_week_number.php?new_week_number=123`

Comment: Thank you very much for reply! I understood your idea. 
I use ASP (with MVC pattern). So I'm not sure that I can generate javascript in server side in this case. 
May be it's possible to get session parameter via $.ajax({async: false,..}),  but it's not very pretty solution.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know anything about ASP... Can't help you with that.

Answer (score 1):

I have been figuring this out myself. This is what I came up with.

It's 2 folded:

1. it saves the view and
2. it restores the selected date after page load.

The problem I ran into was that the cookie with the current date was set on load/initialize of FullCalendar and after that the cookie was read. I solved this by only reading out the cookie on page load and deleting it. The cookies for the date will be set on navigation.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    calendar = $('#calendar').fullCalendar( {
        defaultView:$.cookie('fullcalendar_defaultView') || {if $_USER.status==1}'month'{else}'agendaWeek'{/if},
        viewDisplay: function(view) {
            $.cookie('fullcalendar_defaultView', view.name);
            if ( calendar ) MySetDate();
        }
    }

function MySetDate()
    {
        var thedate = $('#calendar').fullCalendar('getDate');

        raw_date = thedate + 'stringed';
        raw_split_date = raw_date.split(' ');

        switch (raw_split_date[1]) 
        {
            case 'Jan': raw_month = 0; break;
            case 'Feb': raw_month = 1; break;
            case 'Mrt': raw_month = 2; break;
            case 'Apr': raw_month = 3; break;
            case 'May': raw_month = 4; break;
            case 'Jun': raw_month = 5; break;
            case 'Jul': raw_month = 6; break;
            case 'Aug': raw_month = 7; break;
            case 'Sep': raw_month = 8; break;
            case 'Oct': raw_month = 9; break;
            case 'Nov': raw_month =10; break;
            case 'Dec': raw_month =11; break;
        }

        $.cookie('lof_y', raw_split_date[3], { expires: 2 } );
        $.cookie('lof_m', raw_month,         { expires: 2 } );
        $.cookie('lof_d', raw_split_date[2], { expires: 2 } );
    }

function setMyView() {
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('gotoDate', $.cookie('lof_y'), $.cookie('lof_m'), $.cookie('lof_d') );
    $.cookie('lof_y', null);
    }

    if ( $.cookie('lof_y') ) setMyView();
} );
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do a session state as stated above (Here is a [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581.aspx) for ASP Specific session state).  Under code examples on the linked page are examples of how to save a value to the session state and how to read the value from the session state. And yes you can get the values from the session side to the client side :)

Comment: Thank you for reply. How can i pass session parameter to fullcalendar? I use MVC, so i can only pass this parameter to model (and to static view), but i cannot figure out how to pass it to js, only via ajax request..

Answer (score 0):

I try to do the follows.
Server side:

```
[HttpPost] public ActionResult Create(FormCollection collection){   
   ...  
   Session["curdate"] = asi.appointmentDate.ToString();  
} 
public ActionResult CurrentDate(){  
   return (Session["curdate"] == null) ? null : Content(Session["curdate"].ToString()); 
}
```

Client side:

```
var sd = $.ajax(
                    {
                        url: '<%= ResolveUrl("~/Schedule/CurrentDate") %>',
                        async: false,
                        success: function(data, result) {
                            if (!result)
                                alert('Failure to retrieve the date.');
                        }
                    }
                ).responseText;
        var selectedDate = (sd == "") ? new Date() : new Date(sd);
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar('gotoDate', selectedDate);
```